# Unity Change sprite in sprite renderer in Runtime

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In unity I am using a script to randomly create enemies that attack your player. To do this I need to ***insert a game object***, ***add a SpriteRenderer***, ***name it***, and then ***give it a texture*** which is in **assets**.

Here is my code:

```
GameObject sprGameObj = new GameObject();
sprGameObj.AddComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
sprGameObj.name = "Enemy";

sprGameObj.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = Resources.Load<Sprite>("EnemyImage");
```

The code inserts a game object, adds the sprite renderer and names it however does not add the image "EnemyImage" to the sprite. I have looked online but everyone else is using code similar to mine which doesn't work either.

Does anyone know a solution?

**I am coding in C#.**

---

**Update:**

I tried putting this code inside an already existing sprite and it just removed it's image:

```
gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = Resources.Load<Sprite>("EnemyImage");
```

Could there be a problem with the image itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I`d recommend using some sort of config object for organized and name-independent storing of your assets. In that case you could register all used graphic files in that config and get the asset you need by calling something like 'Config.SpritesData.GetEnemySprite(EnemyType.Orc)' for example.
But for now you can start by checking the path of your sprite in the Assets folder, because Resources.Load works with files in Resources folder only. If the path is right, asset import type also worth checking, because Load<>() method is casting it to a Sprite, so casting result may be null if your asset is not imported as a sprite.
Let me know if you checked this two things and it still doesnt work, I'll give it some more thoughts.

Comment: Okay so I there may be a problem with the file path. Could I try using something like "assets/EnemyImage"?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have realised that I thought the assets folder was the "resources" folder and had put my image in there. I thought resources just meant assets. To solve the problem I have put my image in a folder named resources. Thank you for your help. I'll try not to make such easy mistakes next time.

Comment: Another headsup: `Resources.Load<>()` only works for sprites that are set to single. If you have one that is set to multiple you need to use `Resources.LoadAll<>()`.